# How to load properties using zookeeper as the data source for a spring based web application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, apache-zookeeper

I have a web application which is initialised using spring and built using maven. 
The various properties are loaded using properties files which are statically present. Since various environments require different values for the same properties, i use maven profiles to load different properties files depending upon the environment at build time.
Ex:- dev.properties for dev environment and prod.properties for production environment.

Now i want to make the *build independent of the properties files*,
The value of the properties will be fetched from some datasource(zookeeper) during context initialisation.

**How to load the properties before the context is initialised?**

Comment: I have searched google, but could not get definite answer. Getting confused between the various hooks spring provides to initilise. Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: **Spring Profiles** come to the rescue!  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-environment

Comment: I dont want to specify 'dev' or 'production'. Whatever i provide as the environment variable, it should query the datasource and load the appropriate properties. That can even be an 'xyz' environment which i do not know beforehand @ArtemBilan

Comment: Take a look to this `org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration`

Comment: The source of the configuration is zookeeper and not database. The actual question is how to load the properties programatically using some custom datasource, without using static files? And when should i do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Properties` is just one of Java class and that Apache Configuration project exactly provides such an abstraction. I just showed you a sample for JDBC, but there is really many other stuff there. Here is a sample how I load properties from DB StoredProcedure:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="DS"/>

<bean id="storedProcedureConfiguration" class="com.my.proj.config.StoredProcedureConfiguration"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:sqlQuery="pki_props.getProperties"/>


<bean id="propertiesFromDB" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
      p:staticMethod="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter.getProperties"
      p:arguments-ref="storedProcedureConfiguration"/>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertiesFromDB"/>
```

So, you can implement your own `AbstractConfiguration` to load `Properties` from Zookeeper and inject it to the `<context:property-placeholder>`.

Answer (score 4):

[Spring Cloud Config Zookeeper](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper) offers a way to do that. I posted a brief example of use  [here](http://www.therore.net/java/2015/05/03/distributed-configuration-with-zookeeper-curator-and-spring-cloud-config.html)

Answer (score -1):

In the java constructor, simply set a connection to the Zookeeper server and  get the needed data using the zookeeper client methods. You can find examples here: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/javaExample.html

It would look like this (but you would have to elaborate this)

```
public YourConstructor() {
Zookeeper zk = new ZooKeeper(host,...);
zk.getData(...);
}
```

Comment: how will i make sure that the properties are substitued before the beans are initialised?

Comment: you can catch exceptions if the getdata or the connection fails